# Rails 3 route matching with tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to setup a redirect that keeps the format of the request.  However, in some cases the format is not specified and I need to account for that too.

I thought format was part of the path so at first I set it up like this...

```
match 'v:api/*path', :to => redirect("/%{path}")
```

However, format is not part of the request.  So then changing it to this will work when a format is specified.

```
match 'v:api/*path', :to => redirect("/%{path}.%{format}")
```

The downside is in some cases the format isn't specified and this results in an error because it can't match on format.

So my question is...  What is the correct way to create this catchall?

The intent is that if a version number is specified to which a version of that route doesn't exist it should go to the root route, without a version specified.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I've figured it out.  Be forewarned, it's ugly though...

```
match '/v:api/*path', to: redirect { |params, request|
  if params[:format]
    "/#{params[:path]}.#{params[:format]}"
  else
    "/#{params[:path]}"
  end
}
```